# How can I use a different schema for a SqlAlchemy model class in a Pyramid application during testing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, pytest

For a pyramid application that uses multiple databases. I am declaring my SqlAlchemy classes like this:

```
class A(MyBase):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'schema_a'}

class B(MyBase):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'schema_b'}
```

I want to test with the type of database that is also used in production (MySQL). However, I am having big trouble changing the schema, because the `__table_args__` are processes very early (at module load time).

I have been trying 'pytest-dbfixtures' that makes it possible to start an empty MySQL database.  For some reason this approach is not compatible with the standard Pyramid `
approach that creates a SQLAlchemy session factory at module load time:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

So now I am resorting to something like:

```
class A(MyBase):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': function_generating_schema_name()}
```

Where `function_generating_schema_name` does some ugly checks to see if code is invoked by a testrunner or not. There should be a more elegant way!

Comment: Same problem here (minus Pyramid). I'm about to try launching another instance of mysqld for testing so I only have to supply different database credentials to the test runner. I'll report back how things went.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by launching another instance of MySQL dedicated to testing. Instead of using a differently named testing database on the same MySQL server, I now have another MySQL server on a different port. Running multiple servers is built into MySQL (see docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-servers.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-multi.html)), here's how I set things up on Debian 7:

- Add configuration for the new server to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Initially, I put it into a new file in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mynewserver`, but `mysqld_multi` did not pick it up there (apparently one can have a totally separate config file and use it with `mysqld_multi --defaults-file=/path/to/file`, but I digress). MySQL's multi server feature identifies each server by a positive integer you can pick, I chose 13:

```
[mysqld13]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld_13.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld_13.sock
port            = 3307
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql_13
tmpdir          = /tmp/mysql_13
log_error       = /var/log/mysql/error_13.log
```

- Create `/var/lib/mysql_13` and `/tmp/mysql_13` dirs, `chown` to `mysql:mysql`
- Initialize datadir: `mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql_13`
- Start the new server: `mysqld_multi start 13`
- Try to connect: `mysql -u root -P 3307 -h 127.0.0.1`. NB, I have MySQL bound to 0.0.0.0 and access it using TCP/IP, I you're on the standard unix socket configuration, mysql needs `--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld_13.sock` instead of the port number.

Comment: That's a nice approach and will also be compatible with testing in Pyramid, because this MySQL instance is not started during the test-run (the problem with pytest-dbfixtures).